# How to sort by blog title and exclude number in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am displaying a list of properties using blog posts in WordPress.

I am trying to sort the properties (e.g. 100 Main Road, 201 John Street, 300 Ann Street) but I need to sort them only alphabetically and disregard the street number? I am able to sort by title, but again, it's ordering by number first:

```
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
```

So the order I would need it to be in is: 300 Ann Street, 201 John Street, 100 Main Road.

Comment: You would need to use a MySQL function to strip the digits and spaces from the address.  I don't know where you're filling in this `orderby` or if it's possible to specify a function  there.

Comment: @Devon I'm using `orderby` on page.php file. Would I need to use the MySQL function in the functions.php file?

Comment: That'd be a PHP function, not a MySQL function.

Comment: Right, but is there a way to strip the number using a php function?

Comment: That wouldn't help, you aren't sorting in PHP, you're sorting in MySQL.

Comment: Gotcha - do you know a MySQL function that can strip out the numbers for sorting the titles?